# Pandas Dataframe Correlation after merge

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
con_server = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server}; Server=link")
df1 =pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(view1, 'SELECT * \
            FROM summary1 WHERE code like (''%300%'') AND\
            type = ''FUNNEL'' AND \
            count > 100 AND\
            date > TO_DATE(''01-SEP-2017'')'\
            )",con_server)
df1['SFC'] = df1['SAMPLE'].apply(lambda x: 'L'+x[2:]+'0000')


df2=pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(view1, 'SELECT SFC,\ 
            DATA_PARAM, DATA \
            FROM summary2 WHERE DEPT like \
            (''%PIN%'') AND CODE like (''%300%'') \
            AND DT > TO_DATE(''20-JUL-2017'') \
            ORDER BY DT')",con_server)

df2 = df2.pivot_table(index='SFC', columns='DATA_PARAM', values='DATA', aggfunc='first').reset_index()
df2 = df2.astype(float,raise_on_error=False)

df = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', on='SFC')
df.corr()
```

Basically I got 2 dataframes from our database, and tried to find the correlation between the parameters. When I print the df, it shows 301 records (rows) and 177 columns. I expected a 177x177 table from the results of df.corr(), but found it only a 86x86 table. It was found that all 86 parameters are from the df1 (before merge). When I created a new dataframe by selecting the last 80 columns which contains only 5 columns from df1, I found the df.corr() results came out to 5x5 table containing only parameters from df1. What did I do wrong here? Thanks!

UPDATE, it looks that the problem is not about pivotable, merge or NaN issue, but the corr() does not handle certain data from query. The df2 shows dimension of 81245x3 with header printed. I would expect a 3x3 output from the corr() function, and got an empty dataframe instead... Any suggestions?

UPDATE-2, I realize the problem is due to mixed type in the dataset. It works fine after add a line like this:
        df2['DATA'] = df2['DATA'].apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))

Comment: It would be easy to understand the problem if you post df1.head() and df2.head() here

Comment: You have NaNs, maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You've done an inner merge. This means that the merged DataFrame will only contain rows that were in both df1 and df2. Also, since you haven't specified the columns on which the data frames should merge, Pandas will merge rows only if all the columns match.

Try specifying the column names on which to match or matching on index.

Take a look at the documentation here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html